# How can i convert a local array to remote json data?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsonp, ionic-framework

I am trying to get this array from a remote server which is connected to a dynamic database of course.

As far as i read from ionic forums i need to use [$http function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) from AngularJS but i am pretty new to AngularJS and current examples seems too much complicated to me like [this one](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/CrInw).

I am trying to convert [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AJqED) to Remote JSON.

HTML Part:

```
<ion-list>    
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
              item="item"
              href="#/item/{{item.id}}">
        Person {{ item.id }} Name {{ item.name }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Array Part:

```
var friends = [
    { id: 1, name: 'G.I. Joe' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Miss Frizzle' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Scruff McGruff' },
    { id: 4, name: 'G.I. Joe' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Miss Frizzle' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Scruff McGruff' },
    { id: 7, name: 'G.I. Joe' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Miss Frizzle' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Scruff McGruff' },
    { id: 10, name: 'G.I. Joe' },
    { id: 11, name: 'Miss Frizzle' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Scruff McGruff' },
    { id: 13, name: 'G.I. Joe' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Miss Frizzle' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Scruff McGruff' },
    { id: 16, name: 'G.I. Joe' },
    { id: 17, name: 'Miss Frizzle' },   
    { id: 18, name: 'Ash Ketchum' }
];
```

I have tried:

1. `$scope.items = jsonp('http://www.garsoncepte.com/json.php');`
2. `$scope.items = $http.jsonp('http://www.garsoncepte.com/json.php');`
3. `var url = "http://www.garsoncepte.com/json.php";
    $scope.items = $http.jsonp(url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jsonp, You will need set callback function to `JSON_CALLBACK` and set your items in callback functions.

```
  $scope.items = [];

  var url = "http://www.garsoncepte.com/json.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

  $http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.items = data;
    });
```

**= DEMO =**

http://plnkr.co/edit/SyMNFBukQsE9B8WQ9Icv?p=preview